# ASP.NET MVC ActionFilter Analog for whole controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to inject behavior for whole controller, like it could be done for action with ActionFilterAttribute

Best regards,
Alexey Zakarov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not understand the question correctly, but I think that you are asking if you can have an action filter attached to the entire class? If so the answer is yes, for example the [Authorize] attribute. (you can obviously create your own.)

The controller can also override the OnActionExecuting/Executed + OnResultExecuting/ OnResultExecuted. (Expand that to inheritance and you can have derived controllers all doing the same thing.)

Comment: I don't want to override controller methods. I want to specify filter attribute that whould override OnActionExecuting behavior. But it will do it for all action of controllers.

Comment: What AJ is saying is that you can stick your [Filter] on the controller type, and it will apply to all actions within that controller.